# how can I populate data from my json to construct grids in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm trying to display data in my `Angular 8` application. My webservice returns the following json:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test name",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "img_url": "url",
            "field1": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "registeredAt": "2020-01-09T22:21:23.272",
                    "amount": 200
                }
            ],
            "field2": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "registeredAt": "2020-01-09T22:21:46.113",
                    "amount": 200
                }
            ],
            "creationDateTime": "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "page": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "last": true
}
```

And for each element of this array I want to display a div with style card, e.g.:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="url" alt="test name">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">test@test.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The code above I put in `app.component.ts`.

I started from modyfing my `app.component.ts` and I entered there:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'myTestfrontend';

  mystructure: MyStructure[] = [];
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getMyStructure();
    }


    getMyStructure() {
        this.api.getMyStructure()
            .subscribe(resp => {
                for (const content of resp.body) {
                    this.mystructure.push(content);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

but it returns the error:

```
undefined is not a function (near '...content of resp.body...')
```

What's wrong here and how can I fix it so that I could display as many cards as there are entries in my json? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .subscribe(resp => {
                for (const content of resp.body) {
                    this.mystructure.push(content);
                }
            });
```

I think your problem is in here, my guess is it would be more correct to do something like:

```
 .subscribe(resp => function(resp) {
                for (const content of resp.body) {
                    this.mystructure.push(content);
                }
            });
```

o google what that means.. maybe it wants (resp) => function(resp) but not sure it might even be looking for () => function(resp)
or maybe even just function(resp) with no arrow.. .subscribe(function(resp) {})

Comment: Thanks! it did compile successfuly, however the function(resp) shows me a warning: `TSLint: Shadowed name: 'resp'(no-shadowed-variable)` do you know why?

Comment: also, in my app.component.ts I added: `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of mystructure">
    <p> {{product.name}} </p>
  </li>
</ul>` but I don't see anything printed in html file, do you know why?

Comment: is mystructure created??  example this.mystructure = [];   if so then that means it is still empty.  i'm not too famliar with the no-shadowed-variable, you'd have to google what that means..  maybe it wants (resp) => function(resp) but not sure

Comment: it might even be looking for   () => function(resp)

Comment: or maybe even just function(resp) with no arrow..   .subscribe(function(resp) {});

Comment: yes, thanks, the latter worked! so it seems like the code inside the for loop is not reachable, probably because the resp.body is empty. However when I print it before, it shows me that there is some content. `console.log(resp.body); for (const content of resp.body) { console.log("test"); }` shows me https://imgur.com/Westycs this <-- there is an object in console, but my for loop does not iterate over it

Comment: the for loop is meant to iterate over an array, so yes, if content.body is not an array, then it will not work.  you might just need this.mystructure = resp.body with no for loop.  it doesn't seem like you have a reason to iterate over all the objects (and that it might not even be an array) so a simple = will probably do the trick?  i edited my answer, but let me know if any more details will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205711/discussion-between-randomuser1-and-jboothua).